# Use XSL so that XML Item/@id becomes Item/ID

Tags: xml, xslt, drupal-6, migrate

How can I write some XSL to change an external document, so that its structure changes from:

```
  <Item id="1">
  </Item>
```

To:

```
   <Item>
         <Id>1</Id>
   </Item>
```

Or can it be done in PHP? I am using a module in Drupal called Migrate and this is preventing me from being able to convert my XML to nodes.

Comment: Could the **Item** element have other attributes on it, apart from **id**? If so, how should they be handled?

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <Item>
    <Id><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></Id>
  </Item>
</xsl:template>
```